# How to make testing cache storage (Redis) in Django with Pytest?

Tags: django, caching, redis, pytest, pytest-django

I am using Django 1.11.9 with `django-pytest` library for testing my apps. Also, I use Redis as a cache storage. My question is — how to make a testing cache storage and set up this with test data before running tests? Similar to the way Django database does it.

I want to add some `key: value` data to test cache storage (in Redis), run tests, and then delete all of this test data (clear test cache).

Comment: You can define custom django settings for test and use them when running tests. In these settings, define own redis cache or copy the `CACHES` from the production ones. If you want to populate the cache before the tests, write a custom fixture that is called before the test and requests the django view that should be cached. Or, if you have some custom stuff to fill, use the redis cli commands directly. You can clear the cache with `flushall` command. Hard to go into details without knowing what exactly you want to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded solution in `py.test` docs:

> Similarly, the following methods are called around each method invocation:

```
def setup_method(self, method):
    """ setup any state tied to the execution of the given method in a
    class.  setup_method is invoked for every test method of a class.
    """

def teardown_method(self, method):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_method
    call.
    """
```

See: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html?highlight=setup_class#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't see how these methods can help. Could you describe the solution some more? Preferably with example?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are also using `django-redis` library then probably best is to use `fakeredis` library and below setup:

In `app/tests/test_settings.py`:

```py
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            "REDIS_CLIENT_CLASS": "fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis",
        },
    },
}
```

In `app/pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = ur_l.tests.test_settings
```

Then in your `app/tests/test_something.py`:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

def test_cache():
    cache.client._clients # check if this points to `fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis` class
    # If yes then anything below should now use fake cache
```